# How to sort a dictionary by descending order numerically

Tags: python

If i've got a dictionary like:

```
{'name1':[3],'name2':[1],'name3':[2]}
```

How can I order it so that it prints out those names in order of numerical value - eg highest number to lowest, so that it looks like ?:

```
{'name1':[3],'name3':[2],'name2':[1]}
```

(python 3.3.3)

Comment: `[1]`, `[2]` ... are not numerical values, they are arrays. Secondly, you didn't show any effort. Thirdly, when you print a dictionary it's random in which order the keys are presented.

Comment: Like Clodion said, its not possible to "sort" a dict in python. You can however create a sorted dictionary using `OrderedDict` instead of the dictionary you currently have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary can't have order. For that you have to use `collections.OrderedDic` That's the only way!

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dct = OrderedDict({'name1':[3],'name2':[1],'name3':[2]})
dct = OrderedDict(sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda t: t[1][0], reverse = True))
print(dct)
```

Result

```
OrderedDict([('name1', [3]), ('name3', [2]), ('name2', [1])])
```

Well, as suggested, a solution without OrderedDict (but using list comprehension) if it's only for printing the list:

```
dct = {'name1':[3],'name2':[1],'name3':[2]}
lst = sorted([[k, v] for k, v in dct.items()], key=lambda ls : ls[1][0], reverse = True)
print(lst)
```

Result:

```
>>> 
['name1', [3]]
['name3', [2]]
['name2', [1]]
>>>
```

Comment: This a comment. Please refrain from pasting comments as answers

Comment: @NickCollins: so, is it a response to your question?

Comment: If the goal is to just print them out in order you don't even need an ordered dict. Plus I doubt that it is intentional, that the value is a list. Your answer is sorting by the first item of the list. OP seems to be a beginner, so maybe you want to elaborate on the data structures in use, to make this somewhat worthwhile :/

Comment: @enpenax: Well, sure, don't need ordered dictionary, but it's really easier! Trying sorting output based on values isn't so simple without converting the dictionary, no? And I don't use lists. But yes OP seems to be a beginner. However, I really that'll be worth explaining other method, no? But I'll try.

Comment: Well I would have directed the explanation towards the fact that the value being a list is kinda useless. Also OP asks for printing so adding how you can read the dict and sort that to print it is worth adding imho :) Good edit, thanks for considering.